# Combine nested repeated fields into array in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have a collection of records, for simplicity say as follows (comma separated):

```
A1, B1, C1 
A1, B1, C1'
A1, B2, C2
```

When I pass it through Beam as a PCollection, I map each into an object using a ParDo.  Now I want to combine them into

```
A1: {
 B1: [C1, C1'],
 B2: C2
}
```

For key-value pairs I can use GroupByKey, but what if the structure is extremely nested where repeated fields can be at each level?  Is there any transforms to combine repeated fields?

Answer (score 0):

You could naively apply the `GroupByKey` transform consecutive times. First group by `B`, then group by `A`. However, this is highly inefficient because all key-value pairs must remain in memory during each `GroupByKey` step.

The `Combine.PerKey` transform is similar to `GroupByKey`, but it additionally allows you specify an accumulator class with custom logic for combining values. These values could be of any type, for example, repeated fields or extremely nested objects.

Reference:
1. Apache Beam [Combine.PerKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.PerKey.html)